# .Net 3.5 and SQL Server 2005 choosing a DAL technology

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm, .net-3.5, data-access-layer

I have a .Net 3.5 web application and need to change old code to use a DAL technology. I need some help on the pros and cons of choosing a DAL. I know of Linq to SQL but heard that it is an old and dying technology and EF 4 (but since I'm using .Net 3.5, I can't use it?). Does the old EF (1.0?) acceptable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [nhibernate, entity framework, active records or linq2sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF 1.0 in .NET 3.5 is, to put it mildly, ..... virtually unusable. Don't do this to yourself...

And yes, Linq-to-SQL isn't being developed any further - but it's fast, it's easy to use - it **just works**! And it would give you a first "taste" of how to use LINQ to do your database querying - you can always upgrade this to EF 4/5/6 later on!

Other serious options would be [Dapper-Dot-Net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) as an extremely simple "micro-ORM" (or others)

Comment: Yeah I read that EF 1.0 wasn't worth it! I'm gonna go read Drapper Dot-Net info now. Thx!

Comment: Is Dapper what stackoverflow uses?

Comment: @chris: yup, that's what SO is using underneath. It's blindingly fast, small - but you still need to have a good understanding of SQL since you basically write SQL statements that get turned into objects.

Comment: hmm i prob will decide between dapper and ling to sql then. Off hand, does dapper require a lot of setup and such? I have to check if my client/production machine can support it

Comment: @chris: nope, it's just a single `.cs` file to include in your project - that's absolutely all.

Answer (score 1):

yep, you're right, you cannot use EF4 on .Net 3.5, but there is another similar technology, and by the way, much older than EF, and that is called NHibernate